# Query on CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate

Tags: soql

select id from Opportunity where CreatedDate < LastModifiedDate LIMIT 1;

Why there is parsing error when we compare CreatedDate and LastModifiedDate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Salesforce does not allow direct field to field comparison in SOQL query. Workaround for this is mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187460&type=1)

In your case, add new formula checkbox field called `CreatedLessThenModified__c` on Opportunity:

```
CreatedDate < LastModifiedDate
```

then the following soql will work:

```
select id
from Opportunity
where CreatedLessThenModified__c = true
limit 1;
```

Comment: This is a good solution. Worth pointing out why his query is an error, though. Field-to-field comparisons in SOQL are not currently supported. See https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000187460&type=1 and https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHAAA0 (which says it's for reports, but is also the idea for SOQL)

Comment: @Aidan good idea !

Comment: N.B. formula fields can't be indexed so query times could be slower than expected - query requires a tablescan